# boolean error java console when trying to build

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, build

I seem to hit a java error in the following java code when i try to clean and build the project:

```
public class DisplayPerson extends javax.swing.JFrame{

String driverName = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
   String serverName = "xx";
                String serverPort = "xx";
                String database = serverName + ":" + serverPort;
                String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:/" + database;
                String username = "xx";
                String password = "xx";

    public DisplayPerson() throws SQLException {
           ArrayList columnNames = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList data = new ArrayList();


    try {

        Class.forName(driverName);
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        // Create and execute an SQL statement that returns some data.
        String SQL = "";
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
        ResultSetMetaData  rsmetadata = rs.getMetaData();

        int columns = rsmetadata.getColumnCount();


        //  Get column names
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {
            boolean add;
            add = columnNames.add( rsmetadata.getColumnName(i) );
            }

            //  Get row data
            while (rs.next())
            {
                ArrayList row;
            row = new ArrayList(columns);

                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
                {
                    boolean add;
                    add = row.add( rs.getObject(i) );
                }

            boolean add;
            add = data.add( row );
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DisplayPerson.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    // Create Vectors and copy over elements from ArrayLists to them
        // Vector is deprecated but I am using them in this example to keep 
        // things simple - the best practice would be to create a custom defined
        // class which inherits from the AbstractTableModel class
        Vector columnNamesVector = new Vector();
        Vector dataVector = new Vector();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        {
            ArrayList subArray = (ArrayList)data.get(i);
            Vector subVector = new Vector();
            for (int j = 0; j < subArray.size(); j++)
            {
                boolean add;
                add = subVector.add(subArray.get(j));
            }
               boolean add;
               add = dataVector.add(subVector);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.size(); i++ )
               boolean add 
                       add = columnNamesVector.add(columnNames.get(i));

        //  Create table with database data    
        JTable table;
            table = new JTable(dataVector, columnNamesVector)

    {

        public Class getColumnClass(int column)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
            {
                Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                if (o != null)
                {
                    return o.getClass();
                }
            }

            return Object.class;
        }
    };

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can avoid this error by changing this code

```
 for (int i = 1; i <columnNames.size(); i++)

       boolean add //here is a missing semicolon
       add = columnNamesVector.add(columnNames.get(i));//variable declaration not allowed here
```

as follow

```
 for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.size(); i++ ){
         boolean add ;
         add = columnNamesVector.add(columnNames.get(i));
  }
```

Leaving off the brackets isn't good idea.

Comment: @ madhawa priyashantha that hasnt worked unfortunately - my build is successful but with red comments. I will provide my new console readout above

Comment: @MrAssistance what? do you still get this error "error: variable declaration not allowed here" ???

Comment: red comments?are u taking about warnings ??post those errors

Comment: @MrAssistance so doesn't your application work ?application can run with warnings

Comment: @  madhawa priyashantha it works, it builds properly and i see the application as expected. However when i try to run it as a standalone application it doesnt work. I thought the reason may be because of these warnings? is that not right?

Comment: @ madhawa priyashantha this was reason for creating the other question which you kindly began answering. I then saw i was getting these warnings and thought the reason for not being able to run this as a standalone is because of this

Comment: i can't say directly without analize your entire application.don't you get any error when after running your application?

Comment: @ madhawa priyashantha The steps i take is to clean and build the application. When i double click on the DisplayDataUsingJTable.jar file nothing at all happens ???

Comment: @MrAssistance hey before you make .jar files just run (shift+f6) your application and check does it work.

Comment: @ madhawa priyashantha, just tried this (the same as run file) My application starts up and shows the desired table from the database

Comment: if you get the desired output what is your problem now?just asking

Comment: @ madhawa priyashantha the problem is it doesnt run seperate to Netbeans. And i got to provide the file to a colleague who wishes to look at the database from his computer who is also on the same network...any ideas what i can do?

Comment: when you run separate from net-beans but in your computer do you get the gui and desired output?

Comment: @ madhawa priyashantha NO, which is what i dont get, how can it run okay in Netbeans but not seperately on the same computer? Could it be a settings issue?

Comment: @MrAssistance i think the reason because you didn't build jar file successfully..goto your project and goto souce package >>right click>>properties >>run >>main class
chose your main class which bring the gui when you run in netbeans

Comment: i have left work for the day, but i will watch this tonight, and get back to you tomorrow once i have given it a go. thanks so much for your help so far

Comment: @ madhawa priyashantha I cant test anything right now as i am not connected to the server. I have just watched the video, and within the code below i dont appear to have anything that is called runnable, is that an issue:                                        Public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException   {
        DisplayPerson frame = new DisplayPerson();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

Comment: Following the first stage of the video, when i click on the JAR file the mousepointer turns into a circular loading icon for about 1 second, and then it stops. That is all that happens. I would thought that even though im not connected to the server the application GUI would open but not work. When im at at work the same thing happens.

Comment: @ madhawa priyashantha I have just created a simple adding application, i managed to run the application in Netbeans, no warnings in the console. I then clean and built it. But no luck same thing happens :(

Comment: @ madhawa priyashantha I managed to get the adding tool app to work outside Netbeans by changing the class as you suggesed to the one that brings the gui!!! as you suggested above. I tried this with my Database application and i managed to get the GUI load up without any data!!! This looks promising!! I cant wait to try this at work tomorrow!!!!!! :D:D:D:D:D:D:D:D:D

Comment: @MrAssistance i created a video at night to show how to make jar working properly.here it is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6U7xkdj6RJs&feature=youtu.be..
but you almost done that

Comment: @ madhawa priyashantha Great i wil have a look at this now. The jar file now opens on my computer without the need for Netbeans. I get the application show with the desired data from the database. However this only seems to work on my computer. When i run it on my colleagues i get 'A java exception has occured' pop up box. I am very close i think

Comment: @MrAssistance what is the exception??

Comment: @ madhawa priyashantha all it says is 'A Java Exception has occured' The title of the popup box is Java Virtual Machine Launcher

Comment: @ madhawa priyashantha i am going to install eclipse as there seems to be much more support for this than Netbeans, do you think thats a good idea?

Comment: @MrAssistance i don't know some use eclipse and some use netbeans.but there is no gui builder in eclipse .when you test your project in another machine don't forget to use entire dist file not only your jar file because there are libraries inside dist folder

Comment: @ madhawa priyashantha oh really no gui builder okay - thats bad. I will stick to Netbeans. I will try that - i can feel im edging closer to get this working. Are you a professsional JAVA programmer?

Comment: @ madhawa priyashanta your video is brilliant i am sure there are quite a lot of newbie java users that wouldnt know this!! many Thanks, I am still working on getting my file open on another computer

Comment: @MrAssistance if you can share your project folder then i can find the problem

Comment: How do i do that? what is involved. I would be more than happy to give you a call and you can walk me through it? bearing in mind the database is sensitive information.

Comment: i don't need your database.i wanna see the structure of ur database and specially project file .so i can run it in my computer after creating a database

Comment: i really dont think my boss would be to happy, if i did that. would you be able to create a video for me to follow?

Comment: everything is working on my computer, i just dont get how to make it work on someone elses computer

Comment: That would be fantastic if you can, I really look forward to it

Comment: netbeans is not installed on my colleagues computer - would it help if that was installed?

Comment: @ madhawa priyashantha I DONE IT, I DONE IT, guess what there was no JDK on my colleagues computer!!!!!!!! I installed it and now it works hahahahhah We did it thank you so much!!!

Comment: @ madhawa priyashantha Hello could you provide some help with:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982726/not-sure-where-to-put-the-java-code-to-prevent-column-disordering

Comment: @MrAssistance take a look at my answer there

Comment: @ madhawa priyashantha Hello Would you be able to provide some help on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042383/from-java-popup-table-to-java-table-within-a-gui

Comment: @MrAssistance i didn't understand it..could you explain bit more

Comment: @ madhawa priyashantha yes sure, so at the moment i run my code and up pops my table with all data inside. instead of the table to pop up with the database readings I would like a a Jframe panel to show with a table inside. Once i press a button the readings appear inside the table of the panel. Does that make sense so far?

Comment: @MrAssistance what?do you mean you have a jatable inside a panel?and you want to open table in new jframe?actually i didn't get it

Comment: @ madhawa priyashantha my fault it is difficult to explain. Okay let me see. So this is is what i would like to see happen. I open my java program. I get a userinterface. within that userinterface there is a Jtable that will not have any data in it to begin with. I then press a button and the data will appear within the table. Does that make sense? The next part would be to have text field box which i would type a number into. This would be a variable in the SQL code. When i press the button the variable in the SQL code will change so that the data brought back will be different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61927/discussion-between-getlost-and-mr-assistance).

Comment: @ madhawa priyashanth hello do you want to team view again?

Comment: @ madhawa priyashanth Hello could you take a look at a new post i made  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26194371/removing-tags-from-dialogue-box