# From Java popup table to Java table within a gui

Tags: java, user-interface

I have the following code below which is connected to our database and brings back the results into a popup table upon running file.

The issue is i would like:
1.a gui to popup first ( I have created a simple frame with a table in the middle called mytable
2.Within the SQL code there is a variable which the user would type,
3.The user presses a button and the data is brought back into a table situated within the gui.
I cant understand how to make the transisiton from having a simple popup to having the results being brought back into a table named myTable within the GUI. or how to link the variable to a text field.

Could someone help please. One i understand this i feel i will be away and can create any number of variables.

```
package JavaApplication2;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;



public class JavaApplication2 extends javax.swing.JFrame{

String driverName = "xx";
   String serverName = "xx";
                String serverPort = "xx";
                String database = serverName + ":" + serverPort;
                String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:/" + database;
                String username = "xx";
                String password = "xx";

    public JavaApplication2() throws SQLException {
           ArrayList columnNames = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList data = new ArrayList();


    try {

        Class.forName(driverName);
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        // Create and execute an SQL statement that returns some data.
        String SQL = "xxxx";
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(xxxx);

        ResultSetMetaData  rsmetadata = rs.getMetaData();

        int columns = rsmetadata.getColumnCount();


        //  Get column names
            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)

            {
            boolean add;
            add = columnNames.add( rsmetadata.getColumnName(i) );
            }

            //  Get row data
            while (rs.next())
            {
                ArrayList row;
            row = new ArrayList(columns);

                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
                {
                    boolean add;
                    add = row.add( rs.getObject(i) );
                }

            boolean add;
            add = data.add( row );
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


        Vector columnNamesVector = new Vector();
        Vector dataVector = new Vector();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        {
            ArrayList subArray = (ArrayList)data.get(i);
            Vector subVector = new Vector();
            for (int j = 0; j < subArray.size(); j++)
            {
                boolean add;
                add = subVector.add(subArray.get(j));
            }
               boolean add;
               add = dataVector.add(subVector);
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.size(); i++ ){
         boolean add ;
         add = columnNamesVector.add(columnNames.get(i));
  }

        //  Create table with database data    
        JTable table;
            table = new JTable(dataVector, columnNamesVector)

    {





                public Class getColumnClass(int column)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
            {
                Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                if (o != null)
                {
                    return o.getClass();
                }
            }

            return Object.class;
        }
    };

table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF); 
table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

//table.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnNumber).setPreferredWidth(columnWidth);

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
getContentPane().add( scrollPane );

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );


    }
          public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException   {
        JavaApplication2 frame = new JavaApplication2();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


          }






  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setFocusable(false);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 1535, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 755, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
}
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */


        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and
```

feel.
             * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
             */

```
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        //java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
```