# removing tags from dialogue box

Tags: java

I am having trouble removing the SSP and /SSP tags from the output of my code which appears in a dialogue box that i am outputting to.

I have tried a few different methods to removing the tags but cant seem to Please can you advise how to amend the code below so that i these tags can be removed. I am pretty new to Java.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package simpledialogbox;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.*;
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.*;

public class SimpleDialogBox {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try {
        String url = "http://bmreports.com/bsp/additional/soapfunctions.php?element=SYSPRICE&dT=NRT";
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
         Elements SSPparagraphs;
  SSPparagraphs = doc.select("SSP");  
  //paragraphs = doc.select("SBP");
  System.out.println(SSPparagraphs.text());

       (Element SSPparagraphs : paragraphs)
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(

        null, SSPparagraphs, "Cashout Prices", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);


    }   

        catch (IOException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(SimpleDialogBox.class.getName())
        .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your dialog

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, SSPparagraphs, "Cashout Prices", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

add '.text()' to SSparagraphs

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, SSPparagraphs.text(), "Cashout Prices", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Then, to get the output on different lines, I changed the code.  I assigned the output to a string, then split it on the spaces.  I then showed the formatted string in the dialog box, and in console output.

```
 package stackoverflow;

 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.logging.*;
 import org.jsoup.*;
 import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
 import org.jsoup.select.*;

 public class SimpleDialogBox 
 {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
         // TODO code application logic here
        try 
        {
            String url = "http://bmreports.com/bsp/additional/soapfunctions.php?element=SYSPRICE&dT=NRT";
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements SSPparagraphs;
            SSPparagraphs = doc.select("SSP");  
            //paragraphs = doc.select("SBP");

            String[] numbers = SSPparagraphs.text().toString().split(" ");
            String formattedText = new String("");
            for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++)
            {
                formattedText += numbers[x] + "\n";
            }

            System.out.println(formattedText);

            //(Element paragraphs : SSPparagraphs)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, formattedText, "Cashout Prices", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        }   
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(SimpleDialogBox.class.getName())
            .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
      }
 }
```

Comment: @ barna10 just tried that, that seems to have removed the tags however i just seem to get numbers one after another seperated by a space eg. 30.4443 30.4322 28.6999 etc. How do i break them up so that the numbers appear in a list?

Comment: I assigned the output to a string, then split it out.  Looked at my edited answer.

Comment: i used your edited answer, however the dialogue box that displays is a row of horizontal numbers, with each number seperated by a space. This makes it unreadable. Ideally i am looking for the output in the dialogue box as a list. Before i removed the tags the numbers appeared in a list..

Comment: I just finished editing the code (should have edited THEN commented...).  Try it now.

Comment: No problem, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ barna10 would you be interested in having a look at this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197957/how-to-put-the-data-into-a-new-column-in-dialog-box