# how to put the data into a new column in dialog box

Tags: java

I am trying to put the output of formattedText1 into a new column.
Currently formatted text and formattedText1 appear in one continuous list. I tried putting a +" "+ between formattedText and formattedText1 but that doesnt do the trick, I would appreciate some help please

```
null, (formattedText) + (formattedText1), "Cashout Prices",
```

Full code below

```
package simpledialogbox;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.*;
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.*;

public class SimpleDialogBox {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
 try {
  String url = "http://bmreports.com/bsp/additional/soapfunctions.php?element=SYSPRICE&dT=2014-10-03";
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

  Elements SSPparagraphs;
  Elements SBPparagraphs; 
  SSPparagraphs = doc.select("SSP");
  SBPparagraphs = doc.select("SBP");


  String[] numbers = SSPparagraphs.text().toString().split(" ");
  String[] numbers1 = SBPparagraphs.text().toString().split(" ");

  String formattedText = new String("");
  String formattedText1 = new String("");

            for (int x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++)
            {
                formattedText += numbers[x] + "\n";
                  }

            for (int x = 0; x < numbers1.length; x++)
            {
               formattedText1 += numbers1[x] + "\n";
            }


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, (formattedText) + (formattedText1), "Cashout Prices", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        }   




        catch (IOException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(SimpleDialogBox.class.getName())
        .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML

(I revised this to account for your two columns)

(NOTE: you'd get a better result with a JScrollPane in a JFrame)

try this:

```
        String[] numbers = SSPparagraphs.text().toString().split(" ");
        String[] numbers1 = SBPparagraphs.text().toString().split(" ");

        //generate table and column heads
        String formattedText = new String("<html><table><tbody>");
        formattedText += "<tr><th>SSP</th><th>SBP</th></tr>";

        //populate table with data in two columns
        //will account for differing amounts of data between SBP and SSP
        int x = 0;
        while (x < numbers.length || x < numbers1.length)
        {
            formattedText += "<tr><td>";

            if (x < numbers.length)
            {
                formattedText += numbers[x];
            }
            else
            {
                formattedText += " ";
            }

            formattedText += "</td><td>";

            if (x < numbers1.length)
            {
                formattedText += numbers1[x];
            }
            else
            {
                formattedText += " ";
            }

            formattedText += "</td></tr>";

            x++;
        }

        formattedText += "<tbody></table>";
```

Comment: Hey Barna10, so sorry for the late reply. I think my question was a poorly explained. In my code i now have two elements SSPparagraphs and SBPparagraphs. All i actually want is for the elements to appear in different columns. I hope that makes clearer sense?

Comment: Hello i have a general question about the code you provided. With regard to  String formattedText = new String("<html><table>"); how does Java know that the code refers to the table from the website? Where does formattedText come from, and how does Java know this refers to the table?  For example in VBA i would refer to the URL, but nothing in that extract refers to the original table. I hope i have explained this okay?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed a general knowledge of HTML tags. I revised my answer to account for the separate data sets, one in each column.

The HTML here are strictly for formatting the text and have nothing to do with the source of the data.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect, shows exactly what i would like. I was thinking about using a Jframe but i am not to familiar with the process yet. I am very new to Java and learning as i go along in a practical way.

Comment: See what i dont understand is how this works String formattedText = new String("<html><table><tbody>");. To me formattedText is a new variable and which shows all the html code that makes up the table. So how does java know the formattedText variable is actually referring to the table on the website? formattedText doesnt appear to me to refer to anything yet actually refers to the table i want. I am little confused

Comment: It is not truly referring to the table on the website.  The number data is stripped from the feed

     String[] numbers = SSPparagraphs.text().toString().split(" ");

Then the data stored in the array 'numbers' is appended to the String variable 'formattedText'

     formattedText += numbers[x];

Comment: VBA is more of a structured language.  I can understand the difficulty.

Comment: Yes its extremely difficult, i have a new problem if you are interested. I am about to post it up

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207743/trying-to-execute-file-every-x-seconds

Comment: @ barna10 I have discovered Jtables from my learning but need some help..please could you take a look at the following q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391972/moving-the-data-from-the-upper-left-cell-to-each-row-of-the-first-column