# Trying to execute file every x seconds

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Please find updated code that repeats every 10 seconds. However the issue is that it creates a new GUI on the screen every 10 seconds rather than ONLY updating the data every 10 seconds. please can you advise

```
package learningfromscrach;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import com.sun.java.swing.*; 
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import static org.quartz.DateBuilder.evenMinuteDate;
import org.quartz.Job;
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule;
import org.quartz.SimpleTrigger;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.awt.Toolkit;


public class Learningfromscrach extends JFrame implements Job {

    Toolkit toolkit;
    Timer timer;

//declare all the parts that make up the GUI    
private JLabel textJLabel;
private JPanel PanelJlabel;//JLabel is actually a parameter in JAVA
private TitledBorder PanelJborder;



DefaultTableModel model;
JTable table;


public Learningfromscrach(int seconds) 
   //tell java to initiate the create interface
        //this is what is passed to the timer every 10 seconds
   {

    createUserInterface();//create method private void createUserInterface//aframe is parameter this has to match the private void
    }

class Learningtask extends TimerTask {
public void run() {
System.out.format("Timer Task Finished..!%n");
//System.exit(0); // Terminate the timer thread
}
}

private void createUserInterface()

 //all the parts to create the userinterface      
{//from here
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout( null);// i am responsible for setting positioning and size of components
        setTitle("Cashout Prices");//setTitle is also a JAVA Parameter


        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setSize((int) (screenSize.width/6), (int) (screenSize.height/1.1));//cast int for width
        setVisible(true);    //makes the java application show



       System.out.format("Timer task started at:"+new Date());   
         String url = "http://bmreports.com/bsp/additional/soapfunctions.php?element=SYSPRICE&dT=NRT";
  Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Learningfromscrach.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  Elements Periodparagraphs;      
  Elements SSPparagraphs;
  Elements SBPparagraphs; 

  Periodparagraphs = doc.select("SP");//counts the number of SSP Paragraphs in the entire document
  SSPparagraphs = doc.select("SSP");//counts the number of SSP Paragraphs in the entire document
  SBPparagraphs = doc.select("SBP");//counts the number of SBP Paragraphs in the entire document

  //DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
//df.format(0.912385);


  String[] numbers1;
    numbers1 = Periodparagraphs.text().split(" ");



    String[] numbers;
    numbers = SSPparagraphs.text().split(" ");

    String[] numbers0;
    numbers0 = SBPparagraphs.text().split(" ");

    //String str = "1234";
//int num = Integer.parseInt(str);

    int tableRows;

    if (numbers0.length > numbers.length && numbers0.length > numbers1.length)

    {
        tableRows = numbers0.length;
    }

    else if (numbers.length > numbers0.length && numbers.length > numbers1.length)
    {
        tableRows = numbers.length;
    }
    else
    {
        tableRows = numbers1.length;
    }
    //model = new DefaultTableModel(col, 90);//50 is number of rows --You don't seem to need this

    Object[][] data = new String[tableRows][3];//3 is number of columns

    for (int x = 0; x < tableRows; x++ )
    {
        try
        {
            data[x][0] = numbers1[x];
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            data[x][0] = "  ";//error
        }

        try
        {
            data[x][1] = numbers[x];
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            data[x][1] = "  ";
        }

        try
        {
            data[x][2] = numbers0[x];
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            data[x][2] = "  ";
        }
    }



     //header.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    //    model = new DefaultTableModel(col,90);//50 is number of rows  

    String col[] = {"SBP","SSP","Period"};
    table=new JTable(data,col){@Override



       public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0, int arg1) {
    return false;
        }};

       JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
header.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    contentPane.add(table);

        //table.setValueAt(SBPparagraphs.text(),0,0); //first number is moves placing down by 2 rows//2nd number is next cclumn and so on
        //table.setValueAt("fgfg",0,0);




        table.setSize(screenSize.width/2, (int) (screenSize.height/1.1));
        table.setBounds(16,50,400,2000);
    table.setLayout(null);
        table.setVisible(true);
//add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);   
  //      table.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
//add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


}     





//to hear this all refers to the contentpane

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */


    public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException, InterruptedException {
            // TODO code application logic here
// BasicConfigurator.configure();
        new Learningfromscrach(1);



        System.out.format("Task scheduled.. Now wait for 5 sec to see next message..%n");


    }




    //next step to understand how to get data into the panel

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jec) throws JobExecutionException {
        _log.info("Hello World! - " + new Date()); 
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're using newJob, shouldn't the class you're giving it implement Job?

Comment: do you mean name the public class SimpleDialogBoxjob?

Comment: Yes, since that's the class you're passing to `newJob(SimpleDialogBox.class)`: you need to declare it as `public class SimpleDialogBox implements Job {` (and import org.quartz.Job).

Comment: i will give it a go in the morning, and let you know how i get on

Comment: You know that you're not assigning your `Job` and `Trigger` to the new `Scheduler`? You forgot to call `sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);` (or you haven't included this to the question).

Comment: Do you have a main method that you didn't post?

Comment: I have updated the code, see above. I have placed public class SimpleDialogBox implements Job { and placed the new import org.quartz.Job, as per Rup's suggestion. I am not clear what you mean Tom, please can you explain. Thats all of the post barna10

Comment: I am officially stuck!

Comment: Okay made some progress but how do i know its updating? See code above

Comment: You should always format your code, it is quit hard to read. As far as I see it, your code has 2 errors. 1. You're creating the scheduler inside the constructor of `SimpleDialogBox`. That means if the scheduler creates a new instance to trigger the created job, he may create a new instance of that class using the constructer where a new scheduler is created. Now you have to of them. Create the scheduler, the job and the trigger in a different method, or in `main`.

Comment: The second problem is that you're creating the scheduler in the constructer, but you're never calling it. Therefore you won't have at least one scheduler running. If you fixed your first problem, then call the new method in your main method.

Comment: Hello Tom, i just dont understand what you mean as i am new to Java and my only experience is VBA :(

Comment: `main` is your starting point if you start your Java application. Everything in that method will be executed and then the program terminated. A constructor will be called if you create a new instance of a class (e.g., `new SimpleDialogBox()`). Your scheduler is inside a constructer, but you're never creating a new instance of `SimpleDialogBox`. Therefore the constructor will never be called and the scheduler created/started.

Comment: okay i will go away and try implement this, wish me luck

Comment: @ Tom Hello Please see updated code, however it seems to create a new instance of the GUI every 10 seconds rather than only updating the data every 10 seconds. Any ideas much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one class, Learningfromscrach.  Within it you have a main function.  Within the main function you create *another instance* of Learningfromscrach which is now passed to your timer to be run every 10 seconds. When it runs in 10 seconds, it creates yet another instance of Learningfromscrach, and so on.

You don't really need to re-implement Learningfromscrach every 10 seconds.  What you want is for the data to update every 10 seconds.  You should be able set a timer on an update function that will run every 10 seconds. (I can't do code examples right now, but investigate this and see how far you get.)

edit: I refactored your project, eliminating the unused elements and adding some methods and a JScrollPane.  Hope this helps.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;


public class Learningfromscrach extends JFrame 
{
    Toolkit toolkit;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    DefaultTableModel model;
    JTable table;
    String url = "http://bmreports.com/bsp/additional/soapfunctions.php?element=SYSPRICE&dT=NRT";
    String col[] = {"SBP","SSP","Period"};
    JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public Learningfromscrach() 
    //tell java to initiate the create interface
    //this is what is passed to the timer every 10 seconds
    {
        createUserInterface();
    }

private void createUserInterface()
//all the parts to create the userinterface      
{//from here
    setLayout( new BorderLayout());
    setTitle("Cashout Prices");//setTitle is also a JAVA Parameter
    setVisible(true);    //makes the java application show


    table = CreateTable(url,col);

    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table,
            ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
            ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
    setSize(getWidth(), 200); //initial size

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    int delay = 5000; //5 seconds
    int period = 5000; //5 seconds

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
    {
        public void run() {
            RefreshTable(url, col);
            System.out.format("Task run..");
        }
    }, delay, period);
}     
private Object[][] GetTableInfo(String url)
{
      Document doc = null;
      try 
      {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
      } 
      catch (IOException ex) 
      {
            Logger.getLogger(Learningfromscrach.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
      Elements Periodparagraphs;      
      Elements SSPparagraphs;
      Elements SBPparagraphs; 

      Periodparagraphs = doc.select("SP");//counts the number of SSP Paragraphs in the entire document
      SSPparagraphs = doc.select("SSP");//counts the number of SSP Paragraphs in the entire document
      SBPparagraphs = doc.select("SBP");//counts the number of SBP Paragraphs in the entire document

      String[] numbers1;
      numbers1 = Periodparagraphs.text().split(" ");

      String[] numbers;
      numbers = SSPparagraphs.text().split(" ");

      String[] numbers0;
      numbers0 = SBPparagraphs.text().split(" ");

      int tableRows;

      if (numbers0.length > numbers.length && numbers0.length > numbers1.length)
      {
          tableRows = numbers0.length;
      }
      else if (numbers.length > numbers0.length && numbers.length > numbers1.length)
      {
          tableRows = numbers.length;
      }
      else
      {
          tableRows = numbers1.length;
      }

      Object[][] data = new String[tableRows][3];//3 is number of columns

      for (int x = 0; x < tableRows; x++ )
      {
          try
          {
              data[x][0] = numbers1[x];
          }
          catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
          {
              data[x][0] = "  ";//error
          }

          try
          {
              data[x][1] = numbers[x];
          }
          catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
          {
              data[x][1] = "  ";
          }

          try
          {
              data[x][2] = numbers0[x];
          }
          catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
          {
              data[x][2] = "  ";
          }
      }

    return data;
}

private JTable CreateTable(String url, String[] cols)
{
    JTable tempTable=new JTable(GetTableInfo(url),col)
    {
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0, int arg1) 
        {
            return false;
        }   
    };

    JTableHeader header = tempTable.getTableHeader();
    header.setBackground(Color.yellow);

    tempTable.setLayout(null);
    tempTable.setVisible(true);

    return tempTable;
}

private void RefreshTable(String url, String[] cols)
{
    Object[][] info = GetTableInfo(url);
    for (int row = 0; row < info.length; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < cols.length; column++)
        {
            table.setValueAt(info[row][column],row, column);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
{
    // TODO code application logic here
    // BasicConfigurator.configure();
    new Learningfromscrach();

    System.out.format("Task scheduled.. Now wait for 5 sec to see next message..%n");
}
```

}

Comment: @ barna10 I will give it a go. Thanks for your tips. I seem to be putting piecing this together with the help from you and books. Apologies for my naievity but this seems so much more powerful and quicker than VBA.

Comment: VBA is a structured language, this is object oriented.  It's a different way of thinking.  Don't be hard on yourself.

Comment: @ barna10, thanks. I am currently looking at creating a timer task in solving my question. if I am extending the JFrame, can i also extend TimerTask in the same line? to look something like this public class Learningfromscrach extends JFrame extends TimerTask {

Comment: Hello I have given it a go, see the code. I havent been able to link the timer class with the todo code. Some help would be much appreciated. Am i on the right track?

Comment: @ barna10 last comment wasnt complete. Hello I have given it a go, see the code.I cant seem to execute this repeatedly, just once. I have searched the net on repeated execution but i cant seem to make that link in the code. Some help would be much appreciated. Am i on the right track?

Comment: I think you may be over-complicating the issue.  I haven't had a chance to fully evaluate your additions, but I will tomorrow morning.

Comment: @ barna10 this is perfect! You are so clever. I am going to go through the code step by step to ensure i understand this, i may have some follow up questions. Your a star!

Comment: Question 1. regarding the following statement table = CreateTable(url,col); I tried searching CreateTable which i assume is syntax for creating a table, however i cannot find anything about this on Google or in my books. Also i find it strange in that col refers to the headings, while url actually refers to the data within the table. I would have expected col would refer to headings and if anything url refers to row titles?

Comment: oh i see private JTable CreateTable(String url, String[] cols), you declare you are creating a JTable called CreateTable. but why does cols refer to the column headers and url refers to the data. How does JTable know this?

Comment: with regard to private JTable CreateTable(String url, String[] cols) where does cols come from? earlier in the code i see col defining the name of the headers. is cols and col different, and how does Java know this?

Comment: CreateTable is a method that accepts two parameters, a URL in string format, and the column headers in a string array.  The method returns a JTable object.  This is no different than when you pass values to a Sub or Function in VBA.  The url and col values are the ones you declared earlier in the class.

Comment: I have come across a problem. I get the following error which appears to happen when the website updates with a new bit of data..Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 87

Comment: would i be right in saying the new row of data is trying to be added to the table which doesnt have any more rows?

Comment: Sort of.  It actually means there are LESS rows of data.  When I wrote the solution for you, I assumed there would always be X number of rows, but if the number of rows is dynamic, you'll need to account for that.  You may want to replace the `RefreshTable() method with a more dynamic solution

Comment: This is a guess but maybe something is wrong here Object[][] info = GetTableInfo(url); when there is a new row of data in the website

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63434/discussion-between-barna10-and-mr-assistance).